# php working with time only

Tags: php, date, time

I'm using timestamp in my php script to handle time in hours, minutes and seconds. Timestamps also record the date but I'm only using time `00:00:00`.

For instance I'm caluclate difference in time

```
$start = strtotime("12:00:00");
$end = strtotime("20:00:00");

$difference = $end - $start;
```

or dividing time

`$divide = $difference/3;`

Should I continue using timestamps for these operations or is there a time-specific function in php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example of how to do this with `DateTime`:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('11:00:00');
$d2 = new DateTime('04:00:00');

$diff = $d1->diff($d2);

echo $diff->h, " hours ", $diff->i, " minutes\n";
```

Output:

```
7 hours 0 minutes
```

Comment: thanks! is datetime a new lib? i have mixed feelings about using classes for time

Comment: @CyberJunkie It's been around since 5.2, though I believe the `::diff()` method has only been around since 5.3

Answer (score 1):

There is no time specific standard function in php as far as I know, what you are doing is fine. However, it is fairly easy to do the calculation on your own.

```
$newHour = $hour1-$hour2;
$newMinute = $minute1 - $minute2;
if($newMinute < 0 ){
    $newMinute +=60;
    $newHour--;
}
$newSecond = $second1 - $second2;
if($newSecond < 0){
    $newMinute --;
    $newSecond +=60;

}
```

Assuming the first date is later than the second this should work just fine

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).
You can call it that way:

```
$time1 = mktime(12,24,60);   // hour,minute,second
$time2 = mktime(16,24,60);
echo ($time2 - $time1);
```

the results are seconds, like **time()** and **strtotime()**

Comment: Thanks and to display in time format would `echo gmdate("H:i:s", $time_difference);` be ok?

Answer (score 1):

If timestamps suit you, then continue using them. There really isn't anything wrong with them (except the unix version of Y2K in 2038 when the timestamp will no longer fit in a 32bit int). PHP alternatively gives you another way to do time calculations with the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class which can calculate the difference between two timepoints.

```
$d1 = new DateTime('11:00:00');
$d2 = new DateTime('04:00:00');

$diff = $d1->diff($d2);

echo $diff->h, " hours ", $diff->i, " minutes\n";
```