# Convert day hour-minute just to hour-minute

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have this code

```
echo $workedtime->format('d H:i');  //shows 01 10:01
```

I want it to show 34:01!

How can I do it?

Comment: May be change your format string a bit, e.g. remove the "day" part?

Comment: If I do that it shows 10:01

Comment: Umm... why "34"?

Comment: 1day = 24:00 -----> . 24:00 + 10:01 = 34:01

Comment: What format is `$workedtime` in?

Comment: workedtime format is datetime

Comment: Why is your time interval in a datetime format? You wouldn't say "I've worked January 1st 1970, 2 o' clock hours"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php working with time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925489/php-working-with-time-only)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two variables for this, where one of them is for when you started working and the second one is for when you finished work.

This could easily be solved by getting the date in UNIX timestamp for each variables.

```
function timeAgo($startTime, $endTime){
  $seconds = strtotime($endTime) - strtotime($startTime);
  $minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
  $hours = floor($seconds / 60 / 60);
  return $hours . ":" . $minutes;
}

$startTime = "2018-12-24 09:00:00";
$endTime = "2018-12-25 15:30:00";
echo timeAgo($startTime, $endTime);
```

This returns `30:30`

If you're using DateTime, you can just output the DateTime as UNIX timestamp instead of using strtotime. (Assuming you pass the DateTime as arguments for the function).

```
function timeAgo($startTime, $endTime){
  $seconds = $endTime->getTimestamp() - $startTime->getTimestamp();
  $minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
  $hours = floor($seconds / 60 / 60);
  return $hours . ":" . $minutes;
}

echo timeAgo($startTime, $endTime); // $startTime and $endTime has to be DateTime.
```